# play framework 2.6 access log not working

Tags: logging, playframework, logback

I tried setting following in my logback.xml . I can see access.log file being generated in logs directory but no logs is written when I am making http requests to play server. Application logs are being written in regular application.log file but nothing in access.log

Example in docs says logger name should be "access". wonder if that's incorrect.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger

```
<appender name="ACCESS_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/access.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>access-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 1 week worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} %message%n</pattern>
        <!-- this quadruples logging throughput -->
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- additivity=false ensures access log data only goes to the access log -->
<logger name="access" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_FILE" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an "access" logger by default. You would have to create that yourself, e.g. by defining a filter which logs each request to the Logger you created.

Comment: thanks for confirming my doubt. I was looking for access-log module for play and i found some very old version so I assumed that new play artifact might be including that by default. Filters indeed seems like a suitable approach in that case.